# Obj-C crashes on substringWithRange message

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

The following code is making my app crash at line 3 without an error I would recognize or know how to deal with. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

```
NSInteger *match = [str1 intValue] + [str2 intValue];
NSString *strrep = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", match];
label.text = [strrep substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1,3)];
```

Comment: Does it actually give an error and what is it? Also how is `label` defined? Could it be a problem in `[label setText]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you break line 3 into two lines, in order to isolate the issue.

```
NSString *result = [strrep substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1,3)];
label.text = result;
```

If I had to guess, I'd say label has probably been released somewhere, and you are trying to assign to a bad location.

Comment: So that fixed your bug?

Chaining methods together is great for saving space and for making code more readable, but decomposing into multiple steps can be a bit help in debugging.  It's almost always the first thing I do.

Answer (score 6):

You want `NSInteger match`. No pointer. (NSInteger is not a class, it is just a typedef for `int` or `long` depending on your compilation target.)

Although, bizarrely, you code will probably still actually work like this, since the pointer itself will act in place of the int.

Answer (score 3):

If your string is less than (1 + 3) 4 characters long, this will crash.

Comment: Specifically, `substringWithRange:` will raise a `NSRangeException` in that case.

Comment: Thanks, but it crashes when strrep string is longer than 4 chars too :(